# Why does my code only print the last value in a list?

Tags: r, list

I am trying to solve this problem:

```
# Use sample() to randomly select m integers from a vector y.
# If input values are less than or equal to 100 & divisible by 3, then assign these values into a vector s.
# If input values are greater than 100 & divisible by 4, then assign these values into a vector d.
# Return a list l which contains the selected me integers, s & d.
# Do not use the function which()
# Apply the function to a sample which contains 20 randomly selected integers from vec = c(1:200).  Show the output.
```

```
a <- c(99, 33, 104, 98, 108, 105)


myfun <- function(y){
  x <- sample(y)
  s <- NULL
  d <- NULL
  for(i in x){
    if (i<=100 && i%%3==0)
      s <- print(i)
    if (i>100 && i%%4==0)
      d <- print(i)
  }
  s <- sapply(s, list)
  d <- sapply(d, list)
  l <- list(s,d)
  l[["d"]] <- d   # trying to label values in vector d
  l[["s"]] <- s   # trying to label values in vector s 
  return(l)
}

myfun(a)
```

Why do I only get one value in each part of the list, s & d?  Any tips?

Comment: You are overwriting `s` (and `d`) each time the condition is met. If you want to stick with the loop (which is against R's efficiencies, btw), then consider `s <- append(s, print(i))`, assuming you must have `print` in order to see when the assignment occurs (otherwise just `s <- append(s, i)`).

Comment: Replace `sapply(s, list)` with `as.list(s)` if you really need that. Arguably your last six lines of code can be replaced with `list(d=as.list(d),s=as.list(s))` (a one-liner, no need for the literal `return(.)`), though frankly I would much prefer `list(d=d,s=s)`.

Comment: FYI, you aren't yet meeting the letter of the assignment: it requires sampling m integers from a vector y, so a start would be `x <- sample(y, m)` (adding `m=` as an argument to your function); however, that alone is error-prone unless you check for the condition of `m > length(y)` or add `replace=TRUE` (which doesn't make sense to me here).

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY  This is my updated code:
myfun <- function(y){
  x <- sample(y, m, replace = TRUE)
  s <- NULL
  d <- NULL
  m <- 20
  for(i in x){
    if (i<=100 && i%%3==0)
      s <- append(s, print(i))
    if (i>100 && i%%4==0)
      d <- append(d, print(i))
  }
  l <- list(s = s, d = d)
  return(l)
}
What am I missing with the m?!

Comment: You are using `m` without defining it, _bad practice_. It will work as hoped whenever `m` is visible in the calling environment, but if/when you restart R and define your function but forget to define it elsewhere, your function will fail. Make it an argument to your function at least with a default value, such as `myfun <- function(y, m = length(y)) ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code `s` and `d` are not lists, in the for loop they are replaced for each `i`

this will work

```
a <- c(99, 33, 104, 98, 108, 105)

myfun <- function(y){
  x <- sample(y)
  s <- NULL
  d <- NULL
  for(i in x){
    if (i<=100 && i%%3==0)
      s <- append(s, print(i))
    if (i>100 && i%%4==0)
      d <- append(d, print(i))
  }
  l <- list(s= s,d= d)
  return(l)
}

myfun(a)
```